# Error launching sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

I try to run sqlplus on my server with the command `sqlplus /as sysdba`

and I got this error

> sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1: file too short

**Update**

```
[user@server]$echo $PATH    
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/l‌​ocal/games:/usr/games
```

the output of `which sqlplus` is `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus`

I set up all the necessary Oracle shell variables.

I took a look at the `libclntsh.so.12.1` file and it is empty.

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Show the output of "echo $PATH".

Comment: `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: And the output of "which sqlplus"? What user are you? Have you set all the necessary Oracle shell variables - ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID &c?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10839/admin_ora.htm#UNXAR118).

Comment: the output of "which sqlplus" is `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus`
Yes i set up all the necessary Oracle shell variables

Comment: i took a look at the libclntsh.so.12.1 file and it is empty

Comment: Please edit all this additional information into the question.

Comment: Have you patched that Oracle Home recently? Did the patch fail? If you recently applied a patch you may want to try reapplying it to see if it works. You should probably also fsck if there is any chance that there might be an issue with the volume.

Answer (score 1):

It is very recommendable to do a dump in another media of all your database before trying anything else, because your filesystem is probably not going well.

You will need to restart the server and run fsck not only because of that file is corrupted, but because the risk of more data corruption, then try to run sqlplus again, if it does not help, you will need the file libclntsh.so.12.1 for an another installation.

But dont try to simple replace the file, it is not a good idea, first you will need to run fsck to ensure the file system is ok or something worse can happen.